# I am experiencing trouble while installing mongodb compass on ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongodb-compass

I am trying to download mongodb compass from the following steps:

> Download the package:

```
wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.12.5_amd64.deb;
```

> Installing Compass:

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.12.5_amd64.deb;
```

But the last command returns error which is as follows:

> dpkg: error processing package mongodb-compass (--install): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for
>   desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ... Processing triggers for
>   gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
>   mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ... Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  mongodb-compass

Instead of error, a compass is downloaded, but that does not open. How could I download?

Comment: I have got an answer on this page -https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109698/dpkg-dependency-problems-prevent-configuration-of-initramfs-tools

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.12.5_amd64.deb;
```

my problem fixed with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to install libgconf-2-4.

So run the following command :

```
apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where your file is downloaded and then run this command:-

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.26.1_amd64.deb
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you exeperience dependency issues.
Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

just after you *dpkg*

I found it from : https://www.atechtown.com/dpkg-dependency-problems/